# Rude comment and followed with mass downvote

Tags: discussion, rude-or-abusive

So I was commenting on this question: [Laravel convert query mysql to model query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480251/laravel-convert-query-mysql-to-model-query?noredirect=1#comment87973859_50480251)

And a user reprimanded me for posting an unhelpful comment for the question. My comment was to direct the user to Laravel Eloquent where the OP question can be answered using "Retrieving Aggregates".

I flagged the comment as rude behaviour.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @ivarni thank you for that. I should have flagged that comment for moderator attention but sadly the spam downvote happened after I flagged it as rude.

Comment: Welcome to the club :) You are now an SO vetersn.. It has become a rite of passage

Comment: No problem. You can still flag the post itself with a custom flag explaining the situation but now that you brought it to meta it will most likely be seen by a mod anyway. One thing you *could* do though is to edit out the users name from the picture, we try to avoid naming and shaming here and people who need to find out who made that comment will still find them.

Comment: @ivarni Will do that now. Sorry, this is a first for me. As Suraj Rao has mentioned this is my rite of passage. :)

Comment: @hungrykoala lol, calling you the noob when serially downvoting in an ineffective manner that will be reversed by the script.  Only a total noob, (as well as other adjectives that would get me suspended), would downvote by more than three a day:)

Comment: Not even a sophisticated serial downvote. This'll be picked up by the script

Comment: There is such a thing as `sophisticated serial downvote`? lol

Comment: @hungrykoala Strategically downvote such that it's not detected by the script. Fortunately, the implementation details is kept secret to avoid gaming the system, that's harder.

Comment: at least they were considerate enough to openly admit to the crime.

Comment: "Read the docs" is a meaningless comment by the way. If you won't even point them to a specific section of those docs why do you even comment?

Comment: @user2285236 some information is better than no information. A comment is only a comment, there are no rules about how complete they need to be similar to answers.